# position of tags in a html page using python 2.7 with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a html page with the given format:

```
<img class="outer" id="first" />
<div class="content" .../>
<div class="content" .../>
<div class="content" />
<img class="outer" id="second" />
<div class="content" .../>
<div class="content" .../>
<img class="outer" id="third" />
<div class="content" .../>
<div class="content" .../>
```

When iterating over the div tags I want to figure out whether the current div tag is under img tag with id 'first', 'second' or 'third'. Is there a way to do that? I have the list of img blocks and div blocks:

```
img_blocks = soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class':'outer'})
div_Blocks = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'content'})
```

Comment: 200,000th python question!

Comment: YAY! 200000! Congratulations!

Comment: Oops, I just retagged a bunch.. ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Dammit you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.find_previous_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling):

```
>>> for divtag in div_Blocks:
...     print divtag.find_previous_sibling('img')
... 
<img class="outer" id="first"/>
<img class="outer" id="first"/>
<img class="outer" id="first"/>
<img class="outer" id="second"/>
<img class="outer" id="second"/>
<img class="outer" id="third"/>
<img class="outer" id="third"/>
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted :). Thanks.

Comment: @Ranjan You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer! And grats again on asking the 200 thousandth python tagged question :D

Answer (score 0):

Not from your current starting point - you need to iterate over all tags, or at least both types of tags, if the tag is of type img then store id if the class is div then the current stored id tells you which container you are in.  N.B. You can use a re in BS to filter just the two types.

At the moment you are removing the context by extracting just the tags.